# Length of a SAS macro variable that contains quotes and commas

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Let the sample macro variable be

```
%let temp="A","B","C";
```

How do you get the array length of this macro variable, which includes quotations and commas? For example, I would want to return length 3.

```
%let length_of_temp=%sysfunc(SOME_FUNC(&temp.));
%put length=length_of_temp;

LOG: length=3
```

Preferably I would want to do it using one established SAS function or line of code, not creating a new function for processing. Here is what I have attempted so far:

- `countw("&temp.",",")`: the quotes create an error when trying to convert it to a string.

> NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "TEMP". 4
>   ""A","B","C"
>
> NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a future SAS 
>                release.  Inserting white space between a quoted string and the succeeding 
>                identifier is recommended.
>
> ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

- `countw(&temp.,",")` and `count(&temp.)`: typical error of function call has too many arguments
- `count((&temp.))` and `dim((&temp.))`
- variations using `%superq` on the above

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of characters in &temp (11 in your sample) or the number of quoted strings (3 in your sample)?

Comment: Number of quoted strings - edited to clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use macro quoting on your macro variable value so that commas do not cause trouble for call to `countw()` function. Use the `q` and possibly the `m` optional third argument to the `countw()` function to let it know not to count delimiters that are inside the quotes.

```
%let temp="A1,a2","B","C";
%let count = %sysfunc(countw(%superq(temp),%str(,),mq));
```

If you want to calculate the count in a data step then instead of macro quoting you can use the `symget()` function to retrieve the value of the macro variable.

```
count = countw(symget('temp'),',','mq');
```

Answer (score 0):

THis works for me:

```
%let temp="A","B","C";

%let count = %sysfunc(countw("&temp", ","));
%put Number of elements = &count.;
```

Results:

```
8002  %put Number of elements = &count.;
Number of elements = 3
```

Comment: What version are you using? This puts a warning note in the log and only works when working in macro environments, not for instance a data step `DATA temp; c = countw("&temp.", ","); RUN;`

Comment: @Anna I would suggest that if you want the question to include the data step you probably should include that clearly in the question.

Comment: @Anna 9.4M3 a note, not an error, but the note has to do with the macro variable not having spaces between elements not the COUNTW, which I assumed you were already aware of at this point since your code above would generate the same note.

Answer (score 0):

The %quote function might be helpful here to mask the quotation marks:

```
%let count = %sysfunc(countw(%quote(&temp), ","));
%put Number of elements = &count.;
```

Comment: I think this answer is misleading, at least without much more information here.  In particular, `","` is not doing what a novice might think - the quotation characters there are characters, not marks, in that context, and so are becoming delimiters themselves; change temp to `%let temp="A", "B", "C";` and you get 5, not 3.

Comment: Additionally, the `%quote` function _is_ useful, but it's not useful for masking the quotation marks, which are entirely irrelevant here - remove the commas and you don't need any macro quoting at all.